# Traefik not finding TLS secret

Tags: tls1.2, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a self-signed `site.dev` certificate with CN=site.dev and ext3 DNS domain including `site.dev`, as a secret in k8s in the `default` ns, with `type: kubernetes.io/tls` and keys: `tls.crt` and `tls.key`. Since it's self-signed it does not contain intermediate certs (it can't).

Traefik is running with args:

```
        - --configfile=/config/traefik.toml
        - --defaultentrypoints=https,http
        - --entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
        - --entrypoints=Name:http Address::80
```

And when the ingress starts, Traefik logs:

`{"level":"error","msg":"Error configuring TLS for ingress default/site-dev: secret default/site-dev-tls does not exist","time":"2019-04-20T21:09:02Z"}`

The ingress has

```
  tls:
  - secretName: site-dev-tls`
```

And this is the output of curl:

```
curl https://site.dev:443/ -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to site.dev (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number

$ curl http://site.dev:443/
404 page not found
```

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get secrets/site-dev-tls --namespace default --as system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller
yes
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`404` means, that there is no service or deployment behind the ingress.

The ingress works perfectly fine, according to the `curl` output

Just deploy something and point the ingress to it. That should solve the issue